# Can Angular project be indexed in Google without Angular Universal?

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, search-engine-indexing, angular.js

I'm working on an Ionic PWAprogressive web app (PWA) and forthere are reasons iI cannot use Angular Universal. Is there any way to index with success inget Google to successfully index the site without using this tool?

I made some attempts prerendering html pages and serving them to robots by targeting User Agent into my .htaccess file but this doesn't seem to be working. A friend told me that i maightI might be falling into 'cloacking''cloaking' penalty.

I would like to know the experience of somebody who faced this situation.

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you use universal?

Comment: I'm using material-design and this is incompatible with Angular Universal.

Answer (score 2):

maybe, maybe not. People have tested how well Google handles javascript. According to this study https://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157 google is able to crawl javascript successfully because now it is rendering complete web pages.

A similar experiment explained on this website page https://react-etc.net/entry/does-googlebot-render-angular-2-without-angular-universal came to similar conclusions although it did find out that anchor links could not Always be followed. You can test how well your website is crawled by google with the webmaster tools of google. https://www.google.com/webmasters/

Comment: I'm using angular 7, everything working fine, but i have this issue: 
Error
30:09.480
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>
https://www.ashiane.house/main.7e2dc532123c3caa38a6.js:1

Comment: also the html is minimum required HTML before loading the angular project it self... no seo, no page data, no nothing

Answer (score 1):

Rather than Angular Universal, there are two other ways to make your web application SEO friendly.

1. https://prerender.io/ which is a third party middle-ware for rendering your PWA.
2. https://github.com/Angular-RU/angular-universal-starter which is an example of how you can prerender your PWA. Actually, it renders your angular routes into separate html files.