# Is Angular 6 Universal SEO friendly?

Tags: seo, angular.js, page-size

I like to create a friendly SEO web application, so I choosed Angular 6 framework Universal to render pages on server side, that's make my applications pages reachable to Google crawlers.

But even if for a small application the average page size is more than 3 MB due a bulk of code added.

So do you recommend me to use Angular framework?

Comment: We get so many questions here from people who can't get their ReactJS or Angular sites crawled.  Don't build a single page application and expect to get search engine traffic.  Those technologies should be reserved for data entry and private data use cases.

Comment: maybe the answer i've posted here can be of some help https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/115805/can-angular-project-be-indexed-in-google-without-angular-universal/118069#118069